# How to constraint several C++ vectors to the same size?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, vector

I have a class containing a set of C dynamic arrays which are all of the same size, with one of the members being the size of these arrays :

```
class stuff {
  int size;
  float *abc;
  float *def;
  // etc.
 };
```

To ease memory management of this class (and a lot of other classes having a similar layout), I would like to use standard containers. However I must keep the alignment constraint provided by C arrays (and vectors) because this data will be passed around in a lot of C functions.

My problem here is that each vector has its own size, which is redundant and can lead to errors if for one reason or another one changes its size and not the others.

Is there a way to force the arrays/vectors/whatevers to always be the same size ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perhaps one case where it make sense to create a class of your own to manage the memory (no business logic, just memory).

You may, of course, articulate this class around vectors:

```
#define CHECK_CLASS_INVARIANT() \
  ClassInvariant inv##__LINE__ (*this); (void) inv##__LINE__;

class Foo {
public:
  size_t size() const { return _a.size(); }

  float* getA() { return &_a[0]; }
  float* getB() { return &_b[0]; }

  void push(float a, float b) {
    CHECK_CLASS_INVARIANT()
    _a.push_back(a);
    _b.push_back(b);
  }

private:
  struct ClassInvariant {
    ClassInvariant (Foo& f): _f(f) {}
    ~ClassInvariant () { assert(_f._a.size() == _f._b.size()); }

    Foo& _f;
  }; // struct ClassInvariant

  std::vector<float> _a;
  std::vector<float> _b;
};
```

We make sure to always check for the class invariant (in mutating methods) to ensure that it always apply.

*Note: there is a slight flow here, if `_b.push_back(b);` throws, then `_a` was extended and `_b` was not, this can be handled in a try/catch block OR as SteveJessop aptly remarked, by (1) reserving enough space beforehand in both vectors and (2) pushing in them.*

Comment: Why on Earth would you turn assertion into a RAII type?

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: because he wants to check the invariant on exit from the scope (it's a post-condition), even if an exception is thrown, or there are multiple `return` statements, or anything else that might cause the programmer to forget to check it in certain cases. In the case where `_b.push_back` throws, the assert will be performed and will fail, correctly showing that the function as written is not even weakly exception-safe. If he'd just written the `assert` at the end of the function, it wouldn't trigger in that case.

Comment: Oh, and I'd say that in the case of `push_back`, the simplest fix is probably to `reserve` both vectors before pushing either of them, rather than trying to catch the exception and undo the first push. But that's just because `push_back` is a special case of a function that can be nothrow with suitable preconditions (enough capacity).

Comment: More importantly, why on earth would you put a semi-colon in that macro? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: particular coding habit, I don't see why I should be bothered to remember to put a semi-colon after I already wrote the macro name. I would prefer not using a macro, obviously, but too many compilers abusively complain about "unused variables" when using "guards" variables...

Comment: @SteveJessop: small question, I know about the absence of exception guarantee, the basic exception guarantee (no leakage, invariants respected), the strong exception guarantee (transaction-like) and the no-exception guarantee... is "weak" the same as basic here ?

Comment: And don't use leading `_` even when it's allowed because it will make people think "Is this code using a reserved identifier"?

Comment: @MarkB: company's policy... (yes, I have much to say about it...) it's been so drilled into me that I have a hard time parting with it. If you prefer something like `mA` or `mB` or even `aa` or `bb`, it's fine with me, you can even take the liberty to edit... but frankly, it's not going to keep me from sleeping tonight :)

Comment: @Matthieu: yes, by "weakly exception-safe" I mean "offers the basic exception guarantee". "Basically exception-safe" just doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general and explicit way to constrain vectors. The constraint will have to be enforced as an invariant of your algorithms; whenever you `push_back` data to one vector, also push it to the other one. (Be sure to keep the vectors `private`.

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping a vector of pairs of floats instead?

Comment: This is what makes the more sense, but I need to be able to pass the data to C-style a function accepting pointers e.g. `make_something(& st.abc[0])`. Changing the layout of these arrays would require to update these C functions which is not realistically feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what your problem is, but it looks as though you want something like this:

```
template<int SIZE> class stuff {
  float abc[SIZE];
  float def[SIZE];
  // etc.
 };
```

There are no memory management issues with this -- you can create a "stuff" class on the stack or heap, and it needs no destructor.

Comment: A template wouldn't work, because the number of elements is only known at runtime.

Comment: @JoshGreifer: by dynamic array one usually means an array whose size may vary at runtime. Also, `SIZE` need not be negative so an unsigned integer (whichever you prefer) would be better here.

Comment: Ok kbok,  Still not sure  I understand: Are they "dynamic", (i.e. the number of elements can vary after construction),   but they are constrained to have the same size, or are they effectively contsructed with a fixed size at run time (the size being unknown at compile-time), and maintain their size throughout their lifetime?  In the latter case,  it's simply a case of the arrays being owned (managed) by the "stuff" class, not using it as a convenience class for referring to the collection of arrays.

Comment: Yes matthieu I agree -- My choise of int was intentional -- when providing code in response to a question I try to make the code snippets as close as possible to the O.P's code -- I always use size_types in my own code!

Comment: @JoshGreifer : The number of elements can vary upon time (which is why I used vectors in the first place).